# How to split the string and retrieve last two columns in perl

Tags: string, perl, replace, split

i want to retrive the last two columns of a string

ex

```
$path = C:\Documents and Settings\ac62599\AC62599_SBI_Release_2012.12.1_int\vob\SBI_src
$path = C:\views\ac62599\AC62599_view\vob\aims


output should be 

\vob\SBI_src
\vob\aims
```

output should come like this . Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be very simple using `split()` and array access. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure you want a leading backslash in the result? That implies an absolute path - i.e. that `\vob` is at the root of the disk volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` to split the paths into directories. You can use a slice to get the last two, then use `join` to concatenate them back:

```
for my $path ('C:\Documents and Settings\ac62599\AC62599_SBI_Release_2012.12.1_int\vob\SBI_src',
              'C:\views\ac62599\AC62599_view\vob\aims') {
    print '\\', join('\\', (split/\\/, $path)[-2, -1]), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex seems to be the simplest solution

```
my ($dir) = $path =~ /((?:\\[^\\]+){2})$/;
```

Which is to say, look for backslash, followed by one or more non-backslash characters, and look for this sequence twice at the end of the string and capture it.

Note the use of parentheses around the variable is required to give the regex list context.

Output for the sample paths:

```
\vob\SBI_src
\vob\aims
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=~m/.*(\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*)/g;print $1
```